# NullReferenceException When Clicking a Task in Workflow Designer

Tags: 2013, workflow-activity, workflow-manager, workflow-designer

When I click on a `SingleTask` activity in Visual Studio 2012 Workflow Designer I get the following exception:

```
-------------------------
Workflow Designer
-------------------------
NullReferenceException:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
-------------------------

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.List.ModelAccess.SharePointSolutionModelStorage.GetAllFiles(ISharePointProject project)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.List.ModelAccess.SharePointSolutionModelStorage.Refresh(ISharePointProject project)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.List.ModelAccess.SharePointCompositeModelStorage.RefreshProjectModels()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport.ListInfoService.GetContentTypes(String BaseTypeId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions.SharePointListService.<GetWorkflowTaskContentTypes>b__10(IListInfoService service)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions.SharePointListService.ConvertValues(Func`2 producer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions.SharePointListService.GetWorkflowTaskContentTypes()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.DesignTime.Activities.Design.Services.ISharePointListService.GetWorkflowTaskContentTypes()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.DesignTime.Activities.Design.ContentTypesProvider.ProvideItems(ISharePointListService service)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.DesignTime.Activities.Design.IndependentDataProvider`1.GetItems(ModelItem owner, PropertyValue propertyValue)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.DesignTime.Activities.Design.SharePointItemChooserViewModel`1.GetItems(ModelItem Owner, PropertyValue PropertyValue)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.DesignTime.Activities.Design.ChooserViewModel`1.PopulateItems()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.DesignTime.Activities.Design.GenericChooser`2.SharePointBaseChooser_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RouteItem.InvokeHandler(RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlers(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case folder Package was accidentally deleted from SharePoint App project. As soon as I recovered the folder everything started to work again.

More details on my blog [NullReferenceException When Clicking a Task in Workflow Designer](http://slavensemper.blogspot.hr/2015/12/nullreferenceexception-when-clicking.html).